# Receives DeferredAttribute instead of value during calling method

Tags: python, django, database, multi-tenant

I'm trying to call the method, the one below:

```
def get_tenant_model():
    return get_model(settings.TENANT_MODEL)
```

Tenant model in settings:

```
TENANT_MODEL = "app.Client"
```

And in this place:

```
    a = get_tenant_model()
    print(a.name)
```

I getting:

```
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f0cf7d746a0>
```

Why I can't get name of Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.name` refers to the name *column* of a specific model *instance*.  i.e. some particular client's name might be "Bob Smith".

But you're not looking for the name of a specific client; you want the class name of *the model itself*.

Use `a.__name__` instead.